# Mapping JPA Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Guys I have a problem to solve and if possible I would like an opinion from you:

I have a "Workflow" entity with a mapping:

```
@EmbeddedId
private WorkflowId id;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany (mappedBy = "workflow", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List <UsuarioDestinoEmail> usuariosDestinoEmail;
```

The "WorkflowId" class:

```
@Embeddable
public class WorkflowId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column (name = "CPROCS_JURID")
private String numeroDossieWorkflow;

@Column (name = "CACOMP_RESER_SNIST")
private Long codeWorkflow;

...
```

The entity "UsuarioDestinoEmail" has the mapping:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "CSEQ_USUAR_EMAIL")
private Integer codigoSequencialUsuarioEmail;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name = "CPROCS_JURID", referencedColumnName = "CPROCS_JURID", insertable = true)
@JoinColumn (name = "CACOMP_RESER_SNIST", referencedColumnName = "CACOMP_RESER_SNIST", insertable = true)
private Workflow workflow;
```

And when I persist a workflow:

```
workflowRepository.save (workflow);
```

It throws an exception "Error: could not execute statement; SQL [n / a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]"

Speaking that a constraint is null ..

In the bank there is already the data in the column "CPROCS_JURID" that I am persisting in. However, the column "CACOMP_RESER_SNIST" that is informed in this transaction does not yet exist in the bank.

Does anyone know tell me any solution for this?